# Entity Framework using wrong tablename for table class when execute Scaffold-DbContext command

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext, scaffold

I use this code to generate my project models:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.;User ID=*****;Password=*******;Database=*******;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=False;" 
         Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
         -OutputDir Models -force
```

After generating the classes, I see that EF generated `PackageDatum` class inside `PackageData` class - that is wrong!

```
public partial class PackageDatum
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool FloorOutOpen1 { get; set; }
}
```

My table name in the database is `PackageData`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disabe pluralization of the class names, use -NoPluralize switch on Scaffold-DbContext. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes#mitigations-18.